# send socket request from one component to different component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

There is a two different component. One is patient and another is Doctor. The doctor can be on any page. When patient fires `join` event from his page to a particular doctor(e.g abc), the node server will then catch that event and will send `JoinAccept` event to 'abc doctor'. Following doctor should get notification that following patient wants to connect with you.

To achieve this, I could able to send 'Join' event up to server but could not able to listen `JoinAccept` event on doctor's end.

This is what I have done

context.js

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

import { SOCKET_URL } from "constants/url";

const SocketContext = React.createContext();

const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socketClient, setSocketClient] = React.useState();
  const [socketUpdated, setSocketUpdated] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io(SOCKET_URL);
    setSocketClient(socket);
    return () => {
      io.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("socketClient", socketClient);
    if (socketClient) {
      const tokenData =
        !!localStorage.token &&
        JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.token.split(".")[1]));
      if (tokenData.user) {
        console.log("user", tokenData.user);
        socketClient.emit("clientData", tokenData.user);
        socketClient.on("connected", msg => {
          console.log("connected");
          setSocketUpdated(true);
        });
        // setSocketUpdated(true);
      }
    }
  }, [socketClient]);

  console.log("socket updated", socketUpdated);

  return (
    <>
      <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket: socketClient, socketUpdated }}>
        {children}
      </SocketContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export { SocketContext, SocketProvider };
```

Patient.js (it will fire Join event)

```
const Patient = () => {
  const { socket } = React.useContext(SocketContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = {
      to: "abcdoctor@gmail.com",
      from: "patient@gmail.com",
      message: "Join a call"
    };

    socket.emit("Join", data);
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Patient</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Doctor.js

```
const DoctorParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SocketProvider>
        <h1>Navbar</h1>
        <DoctorRoutes />
      </SocketProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

DoctorPage.js

```
const DoctorPage = () => {
  const [msg, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  const { socket, socketUpdated } = React.useContext(SocketContext);
  console.log("Doctor socket", socket, socketUpdated);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("socket", socket);
    if (socket !== undefined) {
      console.log("socket join", socket);
      socket.on("JoinAccept", message => {
        debugger;
        console.log("message", message);
        setMessage(message);
      });
    }
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Doctor </h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

server.js

```
io.of("/sockets").on("connection", socket => {
      console.log("socket connection is made!!!", socket.id);

      socket.on("clientData", clientData => {
        console.log(clientData, "CLEITN DATA");
        socket.emit("connected", "connected");
      });
      socket.on("Join", data => {
        const msg = {
          message: "I am joining"
        };
        console.log("socket", socket.id);
        console.log("I am Joining", data);
        socket.broadcast.to(data.to).emit("JoinAccept", msg);
      });
}
```

In my case the server gets `Join` event from patients and then sends event to requested doctor but doctor page is unresponsive. I mean doctor page does not listens the changes i.e it could not listens socket event `JoinAccept` so that it can join patient's request.

UPDATE

changing

```
socket.on("Join", data => {
    const msg = {
        message: "I am joining"
    };
    console.log("socket", socket.id);
    console.log("I am Joining", data);
    socket.broadcast.to(data.to).emit("JoinAccept", msg);
});
```

to following works

```
socket.on("Join", data => {
    const msg = {
        message: "I am joining"
    };
    console.log("socket", socket.id);
    console.log("I am Joining", data);
    io.of("/sockets").emit("JoinAccept", msg)
});
```

But I want to emit 'JoinAccept' event only for a particular doctor which patient has requested for from join events.

Answer (score 0):

On `DoctorPage.js` `socket` is an object, if you put this object as the only variable in the dependency array it's going to run as a loop.

Try switching to the socket id instead, so:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("socket", socket);
    if (socket !== undefined) {
      console.log("socket join", socket);
      socket.on("JoinAccept", message => {
        debugger;
        console.log("message", message);
        setMessage(message);
      });
    }
  }, [socket.id]);
```

Comment: How can this page listens for `JoinAccept` event when this component is not updated?

Comment: Sockets can listen for events anywhere in your frontend, once the socket is opened it can listen for events, events can update states and therefore 'update' or 're-render'

Comment: It did not work. I refresh the patient page only because I have fired event from useEffect then `Join` event was listened on server but server emitting `JoinAccept` could not be listened on doctor's page.

Comment: I have patient page on one browser and doctor page on different browser. I then refresh the patient page so it fires 'Join' event and it fired. The `Join` event is listened on server as well. The server then emitted the event `JoinAccept` but there is no any changes shown on doctor page which is on different browser.

Comment: `io.of("/sockets").emit("JoinAccept", msg)` works instead of `socket.broadcast.to(data.to).emit("JoinAccept", msg);`. But I want to emit that event only for requested doctor by patient.